# How to search a text contains or not in particular column that contain Json object using linq

Tags: sql, json, linq

[image]

I have a table that contains the column "FEEDDATA". In FEEDDATA column the values stored in json object. Now i want make a serach and fetch the data where "AuthorFirstName" key in FEEDDATA column have value "Lalit". I need to implement it in LINQ.
e.g f.FeedData.AuthorFirstName.contains("%Lal%")

In short: I need to implement search on the feedata column and fetch only those records in which key AuthorFirstName contains text "lal" .

Please help.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: I am using LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Really? That is unusual today. What database provider?

Answer (score 0):

Using general LINQ to SQL, you can use the `Contain` method to do a `LIKE` SQL search and find matching records:

```
var ans = db.Where(r => r.FEEDDATA.Contains("\"AuthorFirstName\":\"Lalit\""));
```

Assuming the type of `FEEDDATA` is actually e.g. `varchar` and not a database specific special JSON type.